# OSM data import error on Windows 2012 server using osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I am trying to use OSM data using mapserver (ms4w) on windows.
Set up all tools and downloaded data for this purpose.
http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/georgia-latest.osm.bz2

Extracted osm2pgsql(cygwin package) to C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql

Imported OSM data into Postgresql OSM database using(osm2pgsql) the following commands

> C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql>SET PROJ_LIB=D:\ms4w\proj\nad
>
> C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql>osm2pgsql -U postgres -l **-d osm -p osm** -W -E 4326 -H localhost -S "C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql\default.style" georgia-latest.osm.bz2

I am not sure why is it **-p osm**, anyway it got imported.
Then created mapfile using google.style and run a map successfully on my local PC (**windows 7**).

But, when I tried the same on my **Windows Server 2012** I get the following Errors:

> C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql>osm2pgsql -U postgres -l -d osm -P 5432 -W -E 4326 -H localhost -S "C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql\default.style" georgia-latest.osm.bz2
>
> osm2pgsql SVN version 0.85.0 (64bit id space)
>
> Password:(input correct password)

```
Error: Connection to database failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

When I try removing "-H localhost" it gives another error like this:

> C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql>osm2pgsql -U postgres -l -d osm -p osm -W -E 4326 -S "C:\cygwin\osm2pgsql\default.style" georgia-latest.osm.bz2
>
> osm2pgsql SVN version 0.85.0 (64bit id space)
>
> Password:(input correct password)

```
Error: Connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
       Is the server running locally and accepting connections
       on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have checked the following:

```
Confirmed postgresql 9.4.1 is running on localhost:5432

C:\Users\Administrator>psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost
psql (9.4.1)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgresql.conf contains the following:
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

And

```
The pghba.conf has got:
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
#host all all ::1/0 trust
```

How can I successfully import the osm data as did in local PC?

Answer (score 1):

probably you are not entering correct password.
Please make sure you can access db from pgAdmin.
Then use same user/password (copy&paste).

Comment: Are you sure that is the reason? This would be better as a comment.

Comment: That's most of the time my problem with similar error. I resolve like this.
But as you said It could be put as comment as this is just a suggestion.